# How to show that f:X$\rightarrow${-1,+1} is constant?

Tags: metric-spaces, connectedness

Let $X$ be a metric space such that given any two points  $x,y\in X$ there exist a connected set $A$ such that $x,y\in A$. Then $X$ is connected.

My work: let us consider a continuous function
$f:X\rightarrow\{+1,-1\}$. We need to show that $f$ is constant. Now let $x,y\in X$ then there exist a connected set $A$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$ for $x,y\in A$. Honestly I cannot proceed from here.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't be afraid to try things: Let $x,y\in X$ and let $A$ be a connected set with $x,y\in A$. Restrict $f\vert_A:A\to\{-1,+1\}$. This is continuous, but since $A$ is connected, $f\vert_A$ must be constant. Since $x,y\in A$, $f(x)=f(y)$. Since $x,y$ are arbitrary in $X$, $f:X\to\{-1,1\}$ is constant. Since any continuous function $X\to\{-1,1\}$ is constant, $X$ is connected.

Comment: But sir i think i have shown this in my work. But i dont know how to proceed from here.

Comment: @Sunitdas Read the last 2 sentences of my answer: $x,y$ are arbitrary elements in $X$ and they satisfy $f(x)=f(y)$. So $f$ is constant. all elements are mapped to the same thing, because all elements $x,y$ satisfy $f(x)=f(y)$, as you proved!

Comment: I am really sorry sir and thank you

Comment: @Sunitdas no need to call anyone sir :) I'm probably around your age, I'm glad I could help